# Read YAML file like properties

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml, jackson-dataformat-yaml

I am developing a spring boot project, and I need some external configuration. So I am storing that in a file called "config.yml" placed in "src/main/resources" folder.

Now I want the properties in config.yml to be injected in my class. Now if we use SnakeYML or any other parser, we would need to make Java classes to define the schema.

What I want is I can read the yml just like properties using @Value annotation. For e.g.

```
logging:
  class:
    name:
    location:
```

I need to access "name" or "location" property using

```
@Value(${logging.class.name})
private String name;
```

Is there a way to do that in spring boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to add separate yml. you add custom properties to application.yml or application-{env}.yml
Spring recognise it and you can it via

1. @Value
2. Spring environment
3. Using Spring ConfigurationProperties

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am able to access the properties now, but on accessing Object or arrays in yml, the only way is to use @ConfigurationProperties I guess